# Correct for number of values in each column

Tags: nonparametric

I have eight columns with different number of values and I am trying to do a non-parametric test between them. Should I do any correction for the number of values in each column? I couldn't find a good idea why to or why not to anywhere. If I do need to correct for different value numbers, then what should I do?

Basically i have 8 columns with 2380 values between them with each columns having values ranging between 195 - 451.

Comment: What is the purpose of your test--what is it attempting to determine about these columns?  Most tests refer to a "null hypothesis": could you tell us what your null is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you give more detail?  It may or may not matter.

Suppose you have 10 stacks of coins, each between 11 and 19 coins but always an odd number.  And you look at each stack, coin-by-coin and keep a tally of heads and tails, calling a stack '+' if majority heads, and '-' if majority tails.

If the list of tallies of each stack looks like this: ++++++++++

A simple, non-parametric test will tell you the odds are 1:1000 that was random, and so the likelihood of the stacks being random is very low.

Were that the case there is no need to make any adjustments.  With non-parametric tests, you need to know a bit more about the situation and goals to make a decision, because the stnadrd parametric approaches (like t-test) don't apply.

Comment: Basically i have 8 columns with 2380 values between them with each columns having values ranging between 195 - 451. Does different number of values in each column affect an ANOVA.

Comment: So, you have 8 columns, some have 195 data points, some have 451, and others have something in-between, for a total of 2380?  On the surface, that wouldn't worry me at first sight.  However, what might is having enough overlap.  ANOVA works by looking at all data points that have values in both column1 and column2 and comparing them, column2 and column3, etc.  You may have some column pairs that have very few values in common (i.e., an entry in the same row for both columns).